# wpf change image source

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, imagesource

I know this is an easy question but I can't figure it out or find the answer anywhere.  I'm just trying to change the image source during runtime in WPF using C#.  Whenever the code runs, it just removes 1.gif and has a blank white box, instead of displaying 2.gif.  Thanks in advance.

XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="img" Height="150" Margin="142,20,138,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage UriSource="C:\Users\John\1.gif" />
        </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

C#:

```
string sUri = @"C:\Users\John\2.gif";
Uri src = new Uri(sUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(src);
img.Source = bmp;
```

Comment: The `Height` is set, but can the `Width` stretch to fit the new `Image`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the BitmapImage.
The correct code would be something like:

```
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(src);
bmp.BeginInit();
bmp.EndInit();
```

That should get you your image.

Comment: This code generates InvalidOperationException "Cannot set the initializing state more than once." for me.  Are Begin/EndInit only required if you use the default constructor and set the UriSource property later?

Comment: From your comment, it would seem that your code is calling BeginInit() twice and the second time you call it you get that exception.

Comment: Agreed that BeginInit() is being called twice.  I think your code snippet is incorrect - the calls to BeginInit() & EndInit() seem unnecessary when using the BitmapImage ctor that takes a Uri.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: If you check the date of the answer, you will see that it was posted way before the release of .NET 4.0. At least in .NET 3.5, changes were recognized by BitmapImage after calling BeginInit and before EndInit as you can see in the remarks section of the MSDN documentation http://tinyurl.com/7qajlg5

Answer (score 0):

Obvious questions first: you're sure that the image 2.gif really exists, and that the BitmapImage isn't null when you set it as the source of img?